# Cannot display any errors in php

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server

I have spent several hours trying to get it worked, but nothing helped. 
I need to enable all errors on my local web server. I have tried a lot of different combinations.

```
 display_startup_errors = On
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL (or | E_STRICT)
```

`phpinfo()` shows me Loaded Configuration File

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

I made all changes in this file. But still it shows `display_errors Off`. 
But when I use this code directly in php files - everything works like a charm.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
```

Please help to solve this problem, maybe there is some file which overrides main php settings.

**EDIT**

Surely, I restart apache each time I change something in php.ini file.

Comment: Have you restarted apache after making changes?

Comment: Surely I do this each time I change something !

Comment: `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Comment: Maybe check also files listed in 'Additional .ini files parsed' below the 'Loaded Configuration File'.

Comment: Other idea - maybe you check Apache but run application with php built-in server?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file that could be overriding php.ini

Comment: Did you create any virtual host? If you run phpinfo there then you get wrong information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart Apache. Some changes require that.

In Ubuntu:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I am doing this each time I change something in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Add below line of code in your file

```
ini_set("error_log",(dirname(__FILE__))."/error_log");
```